# How to script User accounts in HDInsight clusters

Tags: azure, azure-hdinsight, ambari

I am automating creation of HDInsight Clusters. I can create the clusters. However, the template creates  ADMIN accounts. We are using Ambari to create the USER accounts manually but would like to automate this. I think I can get a script included as part of the template.

1. I need a script to create User accounts in a manner Ambari would. I have no idea where to start.
2. Creating groups would also be helpful.

Comment: If my answer is helpful for you, you can accept it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.). This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Almost all Amabri  actions can be scripted using the Rest interface of Ambari. See:
[How to use RestSharp with Ambari Swagger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63181329/how-to-use-restsharp-with-ambari-swagger)

I chose to implement a RestSharp interface using Azure Functions triggered by a Cluster
created subscription event. However, these actions can also be implemented with a Curl script defined by a Script Action during or after creation. The Ambari Rest interface is finicky and requires certain headers are OR are not present. Fiddler can be used to listen to the Ambari web client to determine the correct headers. There is a swagger.json file downloadable from a cluster. It is not a very good file, but enough to get started.

I put my client with swagger.json on github:
https://github.com/USStateDept/Azure-HDInsight-Ambari-RestClient

Answer (score -1):

Unfortunately, you cannot create user accounts in HDInsight clusters using script actions and Ambari in Azure HDInsight does not support creating local users and sign in using those users.

- You can add users accounts are only available in HDInsight Enterprise Security Package.

**OR**

- You can LDAP users to login into Ambari UI in domain-joined HDInsight clusters.

**HDInsight clusters with Enterprise Security Package (ESP)** can use strong authentication with Azure Active Directory (Azure AD) users, as well as use role-based access control (RBAC) policies. As you add users and groups to Azure AD, you can synchronize the users who need access to your cluster.

**Reference:** [Synchronize Azure Active Directory users to an HDInsight cluster](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/hdinsight/hdinsight-sync-aad-users-to-cluster) and also you may checkout similar [question](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/23713347-fc0c-4721-965f-eb816d41b705/how-to-create-a-new-user-for-hdinsight?forum=hdinsight) addressed in Azure HDInsight MSDN forum.